# How do you determine which value className attribute takes in reactjs?

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I know that we can use css classes for the className attribute but I see in a lot of tutorials that even if the value written for className is not used in the css file it is still used in the components. Can someone explain why? Or how to determine the value of the className we need to use?

Answer (score 0):

The [HTML `class` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/class) (as set by the React `className` attribute) is a general way to label elements with some meaningful labels.  It can be used for CSS styling, or JavaScript queries like [`document.querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll), or just to make the HTML intent more readable.

In particular, it's common to include classes in your HTML in case you'll need them later for CSS styling or JavaScript queries.  To be clear, there's no list of valid `class` names; you can use whatever names you want, and use or not use them in order code as you wish.